# Cannot Resolve Symbol "response" error in android

Tags: java, android

i have included the retrofit dependency in my project but still i m getting error on response object.
here is my code:

```
public void jsontesting() {

RestAdapter restAdapter = (RestAdapter) new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://app-development.in/doctor_app_cms/doctor_rest/v1/doctors_listing?id=10").build();
    final LatlngAPI get = restAdapter.create(LatlngAPI.class);
    get.get_doctor(new retrofit.Callback<CustomeAdapter>()) {

      @Override
      public void success(CustomeAdapter res, Response response) {
        if (!res.getError()) {
//                    dismiss_dialog();

        } else {
                    /*Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.retrofit_error,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
//                dismiss_dialog();
        Log.d("Error", error.toString());
                /*Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.retrofit_error,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Which  Symbol  Cannot Resolve ?

Comment: Response response - cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my error. The problem was I am importing wrong response.